# sIFR disabling outline when wmode is transparent

Tags: sifr, transparent, outline

When I use sIFR with wmode:'transparent' and click sIFRed text an outline occures. It happens only in Firefox. Can I do anything about it?

When I use solid color outline does not appear, but I must have a transparent background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, but.. There is no ".sIFR-flash". But there is ".sIFR-replaced". So, everyone put `outline: none;` on "`.sIFR-replaced object`" or on all "object".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try adding `outline: none;` to `.sIFR-flash`.